# beamer dark theme

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I have a very simple question - there are a bunch of beamer themes, however, all of them have white background. I would like to use some theme, let's say Warsaw (since it is perfect), however I'm looking for some dark version of this theme.

The most important thing for me is black background - unfortunately projectors are not as good as screens/printed papers, so dark themes are much better for long presentations, etc.

Any suggestions? Ideally, I'd like to change just a line or so in the beginning of my tex file with presentation.

Comment: I think it's the other way around. The projectors are bad at displaying darker presentations. In fact that's why they are usually compared with respect to their *Contrast Ratio*. Another shortcoming is the plots and images that don't have transparent background. They immediately get detached from the presentation and look like they don't belong there. Even if they are transparent then they are pretty much invisible. I have the boredom of countless parliament blue background .ppt presentations experience under my belt :P

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Personally, I don't like presentations with dark backgrounds since my eyes get tired too soon, but that's just a personal opinion. The [`beamer theme matrix`](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) shows a number of color themes that will give you dark backgrounds; for example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{beetle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{fly}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to design your own, you can for example look at those color themes (they are in the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color` in a typical TeX Live2011 installation) and make your adjustments. For example, here'sa variation on the `fly` color theme, but with a black background, as requested:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=black!90}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red!85!black}

\setbeamercolor{item projected}{use=item,fg=black,bg=item.fg!35}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!95!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!90!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!95!black,bg=black!80}

\setbeamercolor*{framesubtitle}{fg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{block title}{parent=structure,bg=black!60}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{fg=black,bg=black!10}
\setbeamercolor*{block title alerted}{parent=alerted text,bg=black!15}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{parent=example text,bg=black!15}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
\framesubtitle{Test Frame}
Test
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\begin{block}{Test}
Test
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simply incredible!! Thanks Gonzalo Medina [I'm colombian too] In last example you resolves a great problem: for legibility and visual rest on darkest backgrounds you opened light areas!! (for formulas and other important texts)
The dark background is useful for bright rooms, to show lot of photos and it's very elegant. I'll mix this with my customization, thanks newly!

Comment: if you're watching on screen, it's probably more readable on black background, I don't know about projections tho. We'll have to see about that one.

Answer (score 8):

This might be similar as above.
I wanted a quick solution. Adding these to a blank preamble, I got a pure black theme.

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
```

Comment: what a criminally underrated answer. Should someone point out its disadvantages?